# Show that a homogeneous equation is invariant under transformation!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, homogeneous-equation

Suppose we have a homogeneous equation,

$Mdx+Ndy=0$

and transformation of coordinates

\begin{align}
x&=k\zeta \\
y&=k\eta
\end{align}
where $k$ is a constant

Comment: If $x_i = k \eta_i$ then $dx_i = k d \eta_i$, no?

Comment: Meaning it won't change thing at all?. It seems weird to write them as

Comment: What is the objective of changing coordinates this way?

Comment: To change the variables and make them easy to use I suppose. Because some equation is not exact but with $y=ux$ we can solve them. But, how to show that?

Comment: It is invariant!

Comment: Are you talking about the exactness of the equation $M dx + N dy=0$? This is true if $M=M(x, y)$ and $N=N(x,y)$ satisfy $\partial_y M = \partial_x N$ and non-exact otherwise.

Comment: You are right. But then with the new variables?

Comment: It follows since by the chain rule $\partial_\zeta M = \partial_x M (dx/d\zeta)+\partial_y M (dy/d \zeta) = k \partial_x M$ and similarly for $\eta$.

Comment: I am quite blurred. lol. Can you explain more of this. It seems like everything is divided $zeta$.

Comment: Using the chain rule $$ \frac{\partial M}{\partial \zeta} = \frac{\partial M}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{d \zeta}+ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{d \zeta}$$ and, simplifying $$\frac{\partial M}{\partial \zeta} =  \frac{\partial M}{\partial x}k$$ since $$\frac{d x}{d \zeta}=k$$ and $$\frac{d y}{d \zeta} = 0$$

Comment: Thanks now I got it! many thanks man!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome!